# How can i enter in Network Security Field

Tags: security

I am thinking of Entering in Network Security Field.

It can be securing windows network , linux network

But  exactly don't ave the full picture how does that area is divided
I only have the vague idea.

i want some position where company call me to check their system to see if its secure.
Or govt can hire to secure network from external access.

Any thing like that

Can anyone give me some idea how can i start.

Is there any scope in that area. How its growing in future.

Are there any certification which ican do to start with

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Career shift to security - learning tracks?](http://serverfault.com/questions/103928/career-shift-to-security-learning-tracks)

Answer (score 1):

For starting you'll need to have excellent understanding of routing/filtering/Kernel internals/memory management and so on. You may also need to be able to write in assembly (at least plus some C/python for example) to understand how are made up payloads for penetration testing.

If you're willing to pass a certification exam, you can try the [CISSP](http://www.isc2.org/) certification, it has a great value while recruiting as it covers the security field widely. You may want to take a look at the  CISSP All-In-One Exam Guide by Shon Harris.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have 3 years experiencein web development very basic linux server/window server. Now i am roughly 1 year full  time free. Which couurses you think i should do to make master in that field. Should i RHCE/ccna/ccnp etc. Because i have 1 year time and i want to get as  much benefit for hat free time
thanks

Comment: There's a lot of theory and practise to learn in order to make a own place in security field, CCNA is roughly a must have as CISSP but for the rest it all depends on how you want to specialize, if pen testing, Offensive Security[http://www.offensive-security.com/information-security-certifications/] has good courses and provide Certifications.